# Vue Dynamic List

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a basic MTG Deckbuilder using Vue.Js. I'm trying to have the user type the card name into an input box then when the button is clicked, the deck list is update with the card name. Currently,the list add's a blank element for the card instead of the card name. Any ideas?

app.Vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <deckBuilder @addCard="addCard" :title="title" :card="card" :deck="deck" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import deckBuilder from './components/deckBuilder'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    deckBuilder,
  },
  data: () => ({
    title: 'MTG Deck Builder',
    card: {
      name: '',
    },
    deck:[],
  }),
  methods: {
    addCard: function(event,) {
      this.deck.push(this.card.name);
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

deckBuilder.Vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <input v-model="card.name" placeholder="Type a Card Name" />
    <p> the card is: {{ card.name }}
    <button @click="addCard">Add!</button>
    <h2>Deck</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in deck">{{ item.card }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'deckBuilder',
  props: ['title', 'card', 'deck'],
  methods: {
    addCard() {
      this.$emit('addCard')
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not emitting any data in your `$emit`

Try this,
  In deckbuilder.vue

```
addCard() { 
   this.$emit('addCard',this.card.name); 
}
```

In app.vue

```
addCard: function(cardName){ 
  this.deck.push(cardName); 
}
```

In html, `v-for` should be this way

```
<li v-for="item in deck">{{ item }}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you push string item instead of object

```js
this.deck.push(this.card.name);
```

Correct template will be `{{ item }}`, not `{{ item.card }}`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
 <!-- Menu Content -->
    <ul class="nav-list" style="overflow: visible;">
      <!-- Items -->
      <span v-for="(menuItem, index) in menuItems" :key="index">
        <li>
          <nuxt-link :to="menuItem.link" :class="menuItem.class">
            <i class="bx" :class="menuItem.icon || 'bx-square-rounded'" />
            <!-- Link Name -->
            <span class="links_name">{{ menuItem.name }}</span>
          </nuxt-link>
        </li>
      </span>
    </ul>
<script> 
 export default {
  name: 'SidebarMenu',
    menuItems: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [
        {
          link: '/',
          name: '_home',
          icon: 'bx-home',
          class: '',
        },
        {
          link: '/blog',
          name: '_blog',
          icon: 'bx-edit',
          class: '',
        },
        {
          link: '/projects',
          name: '_projects',
          icon: 'bx-code',
          class: ''
        },
        {
          link: '/about',
          name: '_about',
          icon: 'bx-user',
          class: ''
        },
      ],
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add details to explain *why* this works?